# "More like this" for a view

Tags: 7, views

I know how to get a "more like this" block for an individual piece of content (as a block in a panel, or whatnot), however these functions don't seem to work with the results of a View.

My site has a few pages that list the content of a specific taxonomy term (Industry).  Each content type listed has an additional taxonomy term associated (Focus Area).

The view that is presented on the site allows the visitor to select the Focus Area, which when selected, limits the content on the page to matched terms.

I'm trying to get a "more like this" block for the results of the view.  There may be other content that matches the Industry and Focus Area (such as an Event or a Career) that we would like presented.

Bonus points if you can help me make the Focus Area selection persistant across the site (so that when the visitor navigates to a different Industry page, their selection for Focus Area is remembered and applied).

Use of Solr is a possibility as well.  We haven't turned it on while in development, but is part of the plan.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter. There is a good README on how to use it: http://drupalcode.org/project/global_filter.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt

Comment: Global Filter certainly solves the Bonus Points question!  Pretty cool module!